# Page Animation Transition

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a beautiful transition using @Keyframe CSS3 and if possible using jQuery to handle the request of the button.

Basically the concept is when the "START ANIMATION" button was click it must animate the pages from page 1 to page 2 exactly similar to this video: 
http://goo.gl/tkyLnS

Here's my HTML:

```
<main>
    <div class="cd-index cd-main-content">
        <div>
            <h1>Animated Page Transition</h1>

            <a class="cd-btn" href="about.html" data-type="page-transition">Start animation</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

ANd here's my CSS:

/* --------------------------------

```
Primary style

-------------------------------- */
*, *::after, *::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #4089a6;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

a {
  color: #283040;
  text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 4.4rem;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Patterns - reusable parts of our design

-------------------------------- */
.cd-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.4em 1.6em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  border-radius: 50em;
  background-color: #283040;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.no-touch .cd-btn:hover {
  background-color: #323c50;
}
.cd-about .cd-btn {
  background-color: #4089a6;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Main Components 

-------------------------------- */
body::after, body::before {
  /* these are the 2 half blocks which cover the content once the animation is triggered */
  content: '';
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  z-index: 1;
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s 0.4s;
  transition: transform 0.4s 0.4s;
}
body::before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateY(-100%);
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
body::after {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
  -o-transform: translateY(100%);
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
body.page-is-changing::after, body.page-is-changing::before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -ms-transform: translateY(0);
  -o-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s 0s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s 0s;
  transition: transform 0.4s 0s;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
main .cd-main-content {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
}
main .cd-main-content > div {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
main .cd-main-content::after, main .cd-main-content::before {
  /* these are the 2 gradient overlay at the top and bottom of the .cd-main-content - to indicate that you can scroll */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
main .cd-main-content::before {
  top: 0;
}
main .cd-main-content::after {
  bottom: 0;
}
main .cd-main-content.cd-index {
  /* .cd-main-content basic style - index page */
  background-color: #4089a6;
  /* vertically center its content */
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
main .cd-main-content.cd-index > div {
  /* vertically center the content inside the .cd-index */
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
main .cd-main-content.cd-index::after {
  background-color: rgba(64, 137, 166, 0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #4089a6, rgba(64, 137, 166, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top,#4089a6, rgba(64, 137, 166, 0));
}
main .cd-main-content.cd-index::before {
  background-color: rgba(64, 137, 166, 0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #4089a6, rgba(64, 137, 166, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#4089a6, rgba(64, 137, 166, 0));
}
main .cd-main-content.cd-about {
  /* .cd-main-content basic style - about page */
  background-color: #283040;
}
main .cd-main-content.cd-about > div {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
main .cd-main-content.cd-about::after {
  background-color: rgba(40, 48, 64, 0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #283040, rgba(40, 48, 64, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top,#283040, rgba(40, 48, 64, 0));
}
main .cd-main-content.cd-about::before {
  background-color: rgba(40, 48, 64, 0);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #283040, rgba(40, 48, 64, 0));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#283040, rgba(40, 48, 64, 0));
}
main p {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: 3em auto;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #535966;
  text-align: left;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  main {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  main .cd-main-content {
    height: calc(100vh - 40px);
  }
  main.cd-index > div {
    padding-top: 200px;
  }
  main.cd-index > div {
    padding-top: 50px;
  }
  main p {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    line-height: 2;
  }
}

.cd-cover-layer {
  /* layer that covers the content when the animation is triggered */
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: #4089a6;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, visibility 0s 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, visibility 0s 0.8s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, visibility 0s 0.8s;
}
.cd-about .cd-cover-layer {
  background-color: #283040;
}
.page-is-changing .cd-cover-layer {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-cover-layer {
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
  }
}

.cd-loading-bar {
  /* this is the loding bar - visible while switching from one page to the following one */
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #4089a6;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.4s 0s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0.4s, -moz-transform 0.4s 0s ease-in;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.4s, transform 0.4s 0s ease-in;
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.cd-about .cd-loading-bar {
  background-color: #283040;
}
.cd-about .cd-loading-bar::before {
  background-color: #4089a6;
}
.cd-loading-bar::before {
  /* this is the progress bar inside the loading bar */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #283040;
  /* Force Hardware Acceleration */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(0);
  -o-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  -moz-transform-origin: left center;
  -ms-transform-origin: left center;
  -o-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
.page-is-changing .cd-loading-bar {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scaleX(0.3);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scaleX(0.3);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scaleX(0.3);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scaleX(0.3);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) scaleX(0.3);
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.4s 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.4s 0.4s;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.3s, transform 0.4s 0.4s;
}
.page-is-changing .cd-loading-bar::before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  -moz-transform: scaleX(1);
  -ms-transform: scaleX(1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.8s 0.8s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.8s 0.8s ease-in;
  transition: transform 0.8s 0.8s ease-in;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-loading-bar {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
  }
}
```

If you could help WORK WITH JSFIDDLE TO CREATE THAT EFFECT and see how can I tweak my codes that will be great. Its really a hard time for me. Hope anyone can help me in JSFIDDLE:

Here's what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/n0tmv50c/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately your JSFiddle doesn't seem to work in my browser, making it hard for me to give an exact answer.
I did watch the video though and I made some code as an example.

```css
a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #0ff;
    transition: width 5s ease-out 1s, height 5s ease-out 1s, transform 1s ease-in-out 0s;
}

a:focus {
    width: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
    transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 5s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#"></a>
```